# Operator overloading c++ (=)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

After overloading the = operator,

```
const Warrior& Warrior::operator = (const Warrior& warriorObj)
{
if (this != &warriorObj)
{
    name = warriorObj.name;
    start = warriorObj.start;
    alignment = warriorObj.alignment;
    strength = warriorObj.strength;
    craft = warriorObj.craft;
    gold = warriorObj.gold;
    life = warriorObj.life;
    fate = warriorObj.fate;
    specialAbility = warriorObj.specialAbility;
    numberOfObjects = warriorObj.numberOfObjects;       
}
    return *this;
}
```

Once i create 2 Warriors in the driver:

```
    Warrior *w1, *w2;

    w1 = new Warrior();
    w2 = new Warrior();

    w1 = w2;
```

If I change one of the parameters of `w1`, it also changes the parameter of `w2` to the same thing...

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: @LokiAstari "don't have pointers" should be "don't manage resources". A shallow copy is fine for classes that have pointers if they don't own them, no? (I might be wrong)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes. Re-reading that I got the wording wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The overloaded operator doesn't get called since you're assigning pointers. You can use

```
*w1 = *w2;
```

or, better yet, don't use dynamic objects at all:

```
Warrior w1, w2;
w1 = w2;
```

Comment: Most C++ programs are dramatically improved whenever you remove uses of `new`. We need to ban the C++ books that teach beginners to use `new` to create objects.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson, Personally, I think it sprouts from starting with something like C# or Java where you use `Warrior w = new Warrior();` Add in a simple * and it works (debatable) in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your `w1 = w2;` is a **pointer assignment** - the `operator=` you overloaded is not invoked here

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning pointers to eachother, not a class instance, so the overloaded operator will never actually be called here in your code.